# SQLite doesn't seem to convert unix epoch correctly

Tags: sqlite

I insert timestamps in a column of type real. The timestamps are in unixepoch format, eg `1505720496876` which is GMT: Monday, September 18, 2017 7:41:36.876 AM.

However, when I perform the query 
`select datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') from history` I get `-1413-03-01 14:07:12` as result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using milliseconds but you need to use seconds:

```
select datetime(timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
from history
```

From the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> The "unixepoch" modifier (11) only works if it immediately follows a timestring in the DDDDDDDDDD format. This modifier causes the DDDDDDDDDD to be interpreted not as a Julian day number as it normally would be, but as Unix Time - **the number of seconds since 1970**.